# MySQL query not working with another database

Tags: mysql

I have this query which is working fine:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name
FROM job j
LEFT JOIN portfolio_job_category pjc ON pjc.job_id = j.id
LEFT JOIN category c ON c.id = pjc.category_id
WHERE j.end_date >= DATE( NOW( ) ) 
AND pjc.portfolio_id =3
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY  `c`.`id` ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

But when I do query below it doesn't work and returns empty rows:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name
FROM commstratjobs.job j
LEFT JOIN commstratjobs.portfolio_job_category pjc ON pjc.job_id = j.id
LEFT JOIN commstratjobs.category c ON c.id = pjc.category_id
WHERE j.end_date >= DATE( NOW( ) ) 
AND pjc.portfolio_id =3
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY c.name;
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Is there a reason why?

Only thing I did was to add database in front of tables...

Comment: the value of portfolio_id you're restricting the results to is different between the two queries, can you check and clarify this isn't the issue

Comment: The query condition is different, how could they to be same?

Comment: And also some error code wouldn't hurt.

Comment: sorry guys it's actually same wrongly pasted

Comment: second one returns no results whereas first one does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try to seprate database & table by this symbol : `

i.e

`commstratjobs`.`job`

so your query will be like this

```
SELECT c.id, c.name
FROM `commstratjobs`.`job j`
LEFT JOIN `commstratjobs`.`portfolio_job_category` pjc ON pjc.job_id = j.id
LEFT JOIN `commstratjobs`.`category` c ON c.id = pjc.category_id
WHERE j.end_date >= DATE( NOW( ) ) 
AND pjc.portfolio_id =3
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY c.name;
LIMIT 0 , 30
```